# How to pass the elements in Array from a list to a List? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

Pre-information

-User inputs data in console

-Save data in an Array of 2 elements[2]

-Save the Array with 2 elements in a LIST

*Now what i try to achieve is that the user can check if search is in the list regardless if its written in lower or upper case.

```
List<string[]>MyList = new List<string[]>();
var[] myArray = new [] { "A", "B" };
MyList.Add(myArray);    

int y = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Inpu what you are Searching For: ");
string serchString = Console.ReadLine();
serchString = serchString.ToLower();

for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
    List<object> oneTimeList = new List<object>();
    oneTimeList.AddRange(myList[i]);

    Console.WriteLine(oneTimeList);

    if (MyList[i].Contains(serchString.ToLower()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yes you have added this");
    }
    else if (!myList[i].Contains(serchString))
    {
        y += 1;
    }
}

if (y == myList.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You Have not entered this Yet");
}
```

My logic(maybe not the best in the planet :P) says that i have to make a comparison of all the elements of the array in turn with the search the user made and if its true continue, And in order to make this i need first to get the information of the arrays of the list and convert them to a list and then convert them to lowercase. 
Every thing goes fine until the part where i try to add the Arrays to the List and all i am adding are Arrays[].

Any Suggestion on how to approach this issue or how to pass the elements of an ARRAY that is inside of a LIST to a NEW LIST?

Comment: You mention that the problem is when you try to add arrays to the list, I don't see in your code where you're trying to add anything to the list.

Comment: yes i took it away from the original code to see if any could guide me in a better solution but it seem that i was some how in the write track.

Comment: Makes no sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like to want to take an array of strings (assumed as you mention lower casing it), add them all to a list, lower-case them and then compare?

This being the case you don't need to do any of that. You can simply do:

```
var myArray = new [] { "A", "B", "C" }
var toCheck = "a";

//Use the IEnumerable<T>.Contains() Linq extension
if (myArray.Contains(toCheck, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    //...
}
```

If you *really* want to add them to a list I can't give you an example using your code, but to "pass elements of an array to a new list" you can do any of the following:

```
//List<T>(IEnumerable<string>) constructor
var newList = new List<string>(myListOfStrings);

//List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<string>)
var newList = new List<string>();
newList.AddRange(myListOfStrings);

//List<T>.Add(T) (adding items one at a time)
var newList = new List<string>();
newList.Add(myListOfStrings[index]);
```

It's worth noting here as well that any of the above references to `myListOfStrings` could be an array of strings (`string[]`) *or* a list of strings (`List<string>`) because they both implement `IEnumerable<string>` which is the type the above methods require (except for Add which wants a single item).

Here is the documentation for [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) that describes in details how to use each of the above (and all other other available methods...)

Comment: Untill that part i had it correct and it actualy works if i input the "exact" information with capitals and lower cases ( i realy dont know why it does work correctly and i will find out latter on ) but the problem here is that realy what i am adding to the list is an array not its elements. if i print this is the output System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object] and this i cant make lower case

Comment: I've updated the answer to help you with the case comparison part (so you don't need to lowercase everything). It also seems that your list that you are intending to lowercase is actually contains more lists?

Comment: i updated my question also to give a little more information. the first mention that you made where i create an Array put it then  in the list and the make the list lower case that is exactly what i need ( maybe there is some other way to do it but if i could achieve that it will work fine )

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(oneTimeList);` will print out the type name because `oneTimeList` is a `List<object>`... you don't seem to be using it anywhere else though?

Comment: that is correct the Console.WriteLine(oneTimeList); i put it there just to verify that exactly ís adding to the list and its a List<object> now how do i access that List<object> and make it lowercase?

Comment: a) why not make it a `List<string[]>` rather than `List<object>` seeing as that's what is going to be used for? b) You can use the `IEnumerable.Contains` extension that takes in `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` so you don't _need_ to lower case the strings in order to compare them (or in this case check they exist).

Comment: IEqualityComparer<TSource> sounds to be right way because my main List is     List<string[]>MyList = new List<string[]>(); and i do use     IEnumerable.Contains  but this only works if the user is inputing the exact information but if the user uses a capital letter or something it doesnt match. could you give an example of how 
    IEqualityComparer<TSource works in this scenario ( i try to read [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) but i cant see how this fit.

Comment: I already did in the answer above... `Contains(toCheck, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` (the key is the _IgnoreCase_ bit)

Comment: everything is fine but i get this error  CS1955 Non-invocable member 'StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase' cannot be used like a method.    and it says that the IgnoreCase is the one responsable.

Comment: i ask for a big sorry i had a typo error and that why it didnt work. now everything is working fine and i can continue. I do appreciate you enduring and helping a little noob like me. Thx